# Windows XAMP MySQL issue

Tags: windows, phpmyadmin, xampp, innodb

While importing a database, SQL suddenly stopped working. The error log is below. Does anyone know what I should do?

I tried to fix it again from the Backup folder but it didn't work unfortunately

```
2023-05-06  1:48:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-05-06  1:48:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-05-06  1:48:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2023-05-06  1:48:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-05-06  1:48:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-05-06  1:48:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-05-06  1:48:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-05-06  1:48:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=146326851
2023-05-06  1:48:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up in total 2 row operations to undo
2023-05-06  1:48:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Trx id counter is 88058
2023-05-06  1:48:30 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 54 pages from redo log.
2023-05-06  1:48:30 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Trying to read page number 15 in space 2, space name mysql/innodb_index_stats, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384
230506  1:48:30 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.4.22-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=65537
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 20294 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()
ucrtbase.dll!raise()
ucrtbase.dll!abort()
mysqld.exe!?_Assign_grow@?$_Hash_vec@V?$allocator@V?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAX_KV?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@QEBD_K@Z()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@QEBD_K@Z()
mysqld.exe!?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@QEBD_K@Z()
mysqld.exe!?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@QEBD_K@Z()
mysqld.exe!parse_user()
mysqld.exe!?ha_initialize_handlerton@@YAHPEAUst_plugin_int@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPEAHPEAPEADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPEAHPEAPEADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?init_net_server_extension@@YAXPEAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?win_main@@YAHHPEAPEAD@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_service@@YAXPEAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysqld_main@@YAHHPEAPEAD@Z()
mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file at C:\xampp\mysql\data\
Minidump written to C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysqld.dmp
```

I tried to take my backups and restore them from the backup folder, but it didn't work.